# What does Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) Diagnostics tell us?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've had reasonable success implementing FCM in my Android App, however getting control of how long it takes to get a message delivered to the device is proving a bit of a challenge and subject to a raft of factors (FCM itself, coverage, wifi/3g heartbeat, priority, sleepiness, idleness, etc, etc).

Obviously, instant push-through is good, however there is quite a variation with the same version of the App on the same device sitting in exactly the same place over a period of time (sometimes I move it and messages burst through). FCM diagnostics are quite useful, and here are some examples;

MESSAGE 0:1485... PERFECT (BURGLAR APPREHENDED)

```
Current Status  Acknowledged
Collapse Key    n/a
TTL     2,419,200
TIME        CURRENT STATUS
Jan 31, 5:33 PM Device connected
Feb 1, 4:44 PM  Accepted
Feb 1, 4:44 PM  Delivered
Feb 1, 4:45 PM  Acknowledged
```

MESSAGE 0:14860... A BIT SLOWER (BURGLAR GOT AWAY WITH TV)

```
Current Status  Acknowledged
Collapse Key    n/a
TTL     2,419,200
TIME        CURRENT STATUS
Feb 3, 11:04 AM Device connected
Feb 3, 11:30 AM Accepted
Feb 3, 11:30 AM Delivered
Feb 3, 11:42 AM Acknowledged
```

MESSAGE 0:1485... DELAYED (BURGLAR GOT AWAY WITH THE PORSCHE AND TV)

```
Current Status  Acknowledged
Collapse Key    n/a
TTL     2,419,200
TIME        CURRENT STATUS
Jan 25, 9:42 PM Device connected
Jan 26, 3:57 AM Accepted
Jan 26, 3:57 AM Delivered
Jan 26, 3:58 AM Device disconnected
Jan 26, 4:15 AM Device connected
Jan 26, 4:15 AM Sent on reconnect
Jan 26, 4:15 AM Acknowledged
```

So, I can see what happened but I haven't had much luck establishing exactly why. Most days it's brilliant (and had been for months), the next day it isn't.

My specific question: Is there any deeper access to status of the FCM transaction..?

I'm particularly interested in finding out whether my "priority" parameter is actually getting through and being processed by FCM. Typical json snippet sent to FCM shown below

```
{"priority":"high","to":"dI3au0W8te...N7F","data":{"msgsndr":"ADMIN","msgtext":"URGENT: UNAUTHORISED ENTRY IN PROGRESS"}}
```

Any tips most appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is there any deeper access to status of the FCM transaction?*

AFAIK, that's about it. No *deeper* details are available from the diagnostics. However if you're having trouble and need of further assistance on what's happening in the background, I suggest you contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/).

For the `priority`, fairly sure that it will always *get through* so long as you declared it properly.

Comment: Thanks AL, I'll get in touch with them and see if there is some way of knowing for sure that the priority parameter had the desired effect

Comment: @rangi Cool. Good luck. :)

Comment: Further to this, I have been in touch with Firebase support, who responded as follows:

Comment: "_Unfortunately, the priority of the message was not recorded thus will not be visible in the diagnostic tool._" and "_Additionally, there is no full message delivery guarantee for messages._" So, it appears that "priority" does work, if as you point out AL it is declared properly, and thus pushes a data message through to the device even if it is in a "sleeping" state and between heartbeats.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @rangi :)

Comment: Unfortunately this just got worse as of 20 Nov 2017 when FCM Diagnostics was removed from Google Play Console. "I understand that FCM Diagnostics was critical to you in troubleshooting FCM messages but unfortunately this has been deprecated.
Rest assured that we are working on something better that should allow a lot more insight into what went wrong during message delivery, but we can’t share any timelines. I’ll share your concern internally and continue to work to get this new feature out. ツ"

Comment: Thanks for sharing @rangi I'm presuming this is a feedback from the Official Firebase Support.