# Does Firebase FCM support retrieving old messages?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) provide any way for a user to retrieve old messages? From the documentation, it looks like messages are thrown away once the client receives them.

I ask because I'm looking to build an IM functionality in my app, and a user needs to be able to see past messages when he closes the app and then opens it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update from the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42015767/4625829):

> Unfortunately this just got worse as of 20 Nov 2017 when FCM Diagnostics was removed from Google Play Console. "I understand that FCM Diagnostics was critical to you in troubleshooting FCM messages but unfortunately this has been deprecated. Rest assured that we are working on something better that should allow a lot more insight into what went wrong during message delivery, but we can’t share any timelines. I’ll share your concern internally and continue to work to get this new feature out.

---

FCM's main purpose is for [Push Notifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_Notification). So to answer directly, No. FCM doesn't keep track of the message you send for you. There is a [diagnostics and statistics tool](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en) you can use, but I don't think this is the one you're looking for.

IMHO, it's the developer's responsibility to keep track of the details they need. In your scenario, you would be needing a database to store the message details themselves, wherein you can make use of [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). There's actually a sample Codelab about creating a simple chat app using Firebase [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0).

Comment: Unfortunately the FCM Diagnostics tool has been removed from Google Play Console